# HTML <button> not working after setting width and margin for body

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html with a button:

```css
body {
  background-color: White;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.container_body_content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.buttondiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #93d00f;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: Green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container_body_content">
  <div class="buttondiv">
    <button class="button"><span style="color:White;font-family:'Roboto';font-weight:bold;">Test Button</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I comment out `width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;` for body, the button works fine and changes background-color to green on hover.

However if I have `width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;` set for body, the button just simply does not work, meaning background-color does not change to green on hover.

What I need is for the button to have this on hover effect even when I reduce the body width.

I can not seem to figure out what is going on, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Strangely enough in the snippet it works, but when I open it in Safari or Google Chrome, it does not, this is how it looks like on my side:

[image: Button not working]

Comment: Seems to work in the created snippet

Comment: I don't think it is happening what you say, it is working as expected hover works after using `width` and `margin`.

Comment: it works fine for me with your snippet

Comment: Works fine for me too, even without width and margin

Comment: I just noticed this as well, strange this is happening to me in Safari as well as in Google Chrome...

Comment: @Raymond_90 you need to explore the page in the Browser Inspector on both of your browsers to see what's going on under the hood

Comment: I am trying to do that right now, I also edited my question and I attached picture of how this looks like on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved, I just found a rogue DIV which I had "laid" on top of my div.buttondiv. In the snippet it works, because I attached just a MWE and left out the problematic part of the code.

This is the part of CSS that caused my problem:

```
#bar-graph tbody tr {
    height: 296px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your insights